# Using Container-Managed EntityManager with Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, wildfly-10

The Javadoc for `PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` states, "If you prefer the Java EE server's own EntityManager handling, specify entries in this post-processor's 'persistenceContexts' map." This causes `PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` to always obtain `EntityManager`s via JNDI lookups instead of using an `EntityManagerFactory`. I want this behavior because my Java EE container (Wildfly 10) provides a [container-managed, transaction-scoped `EntityManager` via the JNDI lookup](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/JPA+Reference+Guide#JPAReferenceGuide-BindingEntityManagerFactory%2FEntityManagertoJNDI). This configuration works well for injecting `EntityManager` fields annotated with `@PersistenceContext` in my Spring `@Service`s.

However, I'm running into a problem with my `JpaRepository` beans: I can't seem to get Spring Data JPA to want anything other than an `EntityManagerFactory`. Is there a way to inject Wildfly's container-managed `EntityManager` into my `JpaRepository` instances? I don't want to use Wildfly's `EntityManagerFactory` because [it vends application-managed `EntityManager`s...](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/JPA+Reference+Guide#JPAReferenceGuide-Applicationmanagedentitymanager)